# Angular UI Router: Access state parameters outside ui-view

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

The menu is located outside a `<div>` block which is rendered via UI Router's `ui-view`.

In order to modify the menu according to the state parameters, I need access to the current state parameters from within the menu's controller, but the `$stateParams` variable is an empty object when used outside the `ui-view` part.

How can I access them?

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$meteor', '$filter',
  function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $meteor, $filter) {
    // ... $stateParams equals {}
  }
]);
```

Comment: You could use `$rootScope`

Answer (score 4):

Try to watch for state changes in your controller...

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$meteor', '$filter',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $meteor, $filter) {

        //this watches for state changes
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
           function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
              //do something when state changes
              state = toState.name;
              postid = toParams.postid;
              console.log(toParams); //this is the stateParams you need
           });

     }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you inject  `$stateParams` into your controller?   Can you provide a code snippet of what you already have?

Comment: Injecting `$stateParams` in a controller outside `ui-view` gives me an empty object (`{}`).